# find_header() in eyeD3, mp3.py finds just a few frame headers

Tags: python, header, mp3

I took an mp3 file of size 405.9 kB and ran the following:

```
# Here fp points to the audio file
# find_header has been imported
def test(fp):
    start_pos = 0
    sync_pos, header, header_bytes = find_header(fp)
    i = 0
    while i < 30:
        start_pos += sync_pos
        sync_pos, header, header_bytes = find_header(fp, start_pos)
        print sync_pos
        i += 1


Output:
102
519
937
1773
3445
14312
21417
85365
127997
None
```

I am confused if an mp3 file has contiguous frames without any headers. Does it also mean that there are frame header formats other than the one described in the following link?
http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm